# Redirection of indexed dynamic urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want make 301 redierects from one URLs to another URLs. For example

This URL //muscleathletes.com/index.php?page=videos&section=view&vid_id=100019 to

//muscleathletes.com/?vid_id=100019

iam  usin this in .httacces

```
RewriteRule ^vid_id=([^/]+) index.php?page=videos&section=view&vid_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

but the rule not working can you help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^vid_id=[0-9]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?page=videos&section=view [R=301,L,QSA]
```